# Pass data from Thymeleaf to the controller using Spring

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Hi I'm new with Spring and Thymeleaf development and I'm trying to understand how to pass the data between Thymeleaf and the controller. I know how to pass the data the other way around. With the data that I'm passing from the controller to the view I'm building a table where i have two columns (one is the button for select the service and the other is the service name) and as many rows as the service that I have. What I want to do is to grab the id of the selected service (when pressing the add button and i can press the single button only one time but i can press all the others) and do some backe-end processing with it (For now i'm just trying to print the value). The other thing is that once clicking on the button it redirects me to the index page but adding /addService at the end of the URL and I don't want that (I want to remain in the same page with the same URL). 
How can i solve this problem?

**index.html**

```
<table id="html-table" class="table table-hover table-clean table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Service</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="serviceOffered : ${servicesOffered}">
            <td>
            <form action="#" th:value="${serviceOffered.id}" th:object="${serviceOffered}" th:action="@{/addService}" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="${serviceOffered.id}">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td th:value="${serviceOffered.name}" th:text="${serviceOffered.name}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addService", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addService(@Valid ServiceOffered serviceOffered, BindingResult bindingResult){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    System.out.println("VALUE " + serviceOffered.getId());

    modelAndView.setViewName("/index");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form has a button of type `submit`. When you press the button, what it does is submit the form. In your controller you redirect to `index` page. If you want to click the button and just send the value of the service without reloading the page, You need to use use jquery's `ajax` call. [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Here is a sample code of ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
url: '/your url',
method: 'post',
data: 'your data'
}).then(function(response){
// do what ever you want with your response.
})
```

REMEMBER: You need to add `@Responsebody` annotation on your method in the controller class.

Comment: Actually, my final goal is to present the selected value into a table right next to the table where I selected the value (Just think about it as a shopping bag that has the list of the selected services). Therefore, I was thinking of using the controller to grab the selected value and then push it back to the front. So probably i will need a refresh of the page but honestly I don't know how to write the whole thing (Maybe it is also possible to do it with some javascript)!

Comment: @andrea you can return the value from your controller. You will get this value in `response`. You can then update the `text` of `div` or whatever your are using. That would be something like `$("#yourDivId").text(response)`

Comment: Have a look into this tutorial. It might be helpful. https://crunchify.com/how-to-use-ajax-jquery-in-spring-web-mvc-jsp-example/